Zethi, Arcane Blademaster and split cards
When exiling a cards with Zethi, Arcane Blademaster. If I exile a split card that is half instant and half sorcery, I can only cast the instant half, correct? Example being Said//Done.

You can cast the sorcery side of split cards that are both.
The rule for casting copies is 707.12:

707.12. An effect that instructs a player to cast a copy of an object (and not just copy a spell) follows the rules for casting spells, except that the copy is created in the same zone the object is in and then cast while another spell or ability is resolving. Casting a copy of an object follows steps 601.2a–h of rule 601, “Casting Spells,” and then the copy becomes cast. Once cast, the copy is a spell on the stack, and just like any other spell it can resolve or be countered.

While Zethi/Chun-Li does only let you exile instant cards, there is no check when the attack trigger resolves that the card exiled with a kick counter on it is an instant. These spells are cast while Zethi's trigger is still resolving and so ignore all timing restrictions, while following the normal rules for casting spells, including choosing which half you would cast.
You are able to cast either half of a split card this way, and could even play the fuse cost for split cards with fuse, or the back side of MDFCs where the front was an instant with the back being a spell (if any of these were printed, none currently exist, all that are instants on the front side are lands on the back).
